# How to determine Android Full SDK Download size?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I'm asked to report Download size of Full Android SDK (Not Disk Size).

**On Disk : 49GB**

**On Network (Downloaded Zip Files): ?GB**

Installed: Windows 7 x64 machine

- Tools till 24.3.1
- Tool preview channel
- Android M
- Android  API (22, 21,20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 8, 7, 4, 3)
- Extras (All Support Libraries, , Drivers, services and repo's, HAXM)

Anyone have numbers?

Comment: Read the Android SDK documentation maybe?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, tried that in first place. it only talking about basic SDK installer size but not after adding API versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the archive size directly in the XML used by SDK Manager:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml

For example the size of `Android SDK Platform 5.1.1` is 66852371 byte:

```
<sdk:platform>
    <!--
     Generated at Mon Mar 30 10:48:23 2015 from git_lmp-mr1-sdk-release @ 1819727 
    -->
    <sdk:revision>2</sdk:revision>
    <sdk:description>Android SDK Platform 5.1.1</sdk:description>
    <sdk:version>5.1.1</sdk:version>
    <sdk:api-level>22</sdk:api-level>
    <sdk:min-tools-rev>
    <sdk:major>22</sdk:major>
    </sdk:min-tools-rev>
    <sdk:layoutlib>
        <sdk:api>14</sdk:api>
        <sdk:revision>2</sdk:revision>
    </sdk:layoutlib>
    <sdk:archives>
        <sdk:archive>
            <sdk:size>66852371</sdk:size>
            <sdk:checksum type="sha1">5d1bd10fea962b216a0dece1247070164760a9fc</sdk:checksum>
            <sdk:url>android-22_r02.zip</sdk:url>
        </sdk:archive>
    </sdk:archives>
    <sdk:uses-license ref="android-sdk-license"/>
</sdk:platform>
```

Comment: Its too much of info on the link. Do you have a single Number (approx.) that you observed while download?

Comment: No I don't have the size of all SDK. You need to search the size in the XML.

Comment: to search only the size, hit Ctrl+F and type sdk:size. Anyway, I'm surprised it's only 60~80MB compared to NDK size which is over 500MB.

Comment: android studio is like 2gb