# What is the actual size of Android Sdk?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, sdk, size

I ask this because, after updating my Android Studio, I found SDK has risen up in size, up to 52GBs while at the beginning it was about 101MBs. Why does it contains too large size?

Comment: Check which API versions you have installed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK is a collection of libraries and Software Development tools. Whenever Google releases a new version or update of Android Software, a corresponding SDK is also released with it. In the updated or new version of SDK, some more features are included which are not present in the previous version. Its size depends on the components you install.

Major components:

- Android SDK Tools,
- Android SDK Build-Tools
- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform-tools
  ...

In Android Studio check what components you have installed.

To determine the Android Full SDK Download size check the following question:
[How to determine Android Full SDK Download size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863818/how-to-determine-android-full-sdk-download-size)